# More coding expressions like while(!(succeed = try()))?

Tags: popularity-contest

I am looking for either suggestions or examples of more famous sayings written in code! If you have a website or database of them, please link that below your favorite one!
Examples:

```
while(!(succeed = try()))


if(lifegivesyou == lemons) {makelemonade();)
```

Comment: I prefer `if(life.gives(you,lemons)) you.throw(lemons,'people you don\'t like')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (glass.getLevel() == 0.5)
    throw new ContainerTooLargeException(glass + " is twice as big as it needs to be.");
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be an OptimismException?

Comment: The optimist says the glass is half full. The pessimist says it's half empty. The engineer says the glass is twice as big as it needs to be.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
~wish&~want;
```

or

```
Penny.Earned = Penny.Save();
```

Comment: Nice ones! I wish I could upvote! MOAR PLS

Comment: Shouldn't this just be 
`Penny saved = earned;`

Answer (score 4):

## bash

```bash
say "It's going to be legen..."
waitforit
say "dary!"
```

Answer (score 2):

## C++

```cpp
Toast toast = New Toast();
toast.fillside("butter", "up");
toast.fall(); //this method swaps sides, now buttered side is down
```